# How can I change my command line (bash) prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

i'm new to ubuntu .presently i'm using ubuntu 12.04 version.I want to know how to change terminal's displaying text.
currently my terminal displaying the text..

narasimha@narasimha:~$

how can i change it with narasimha@reddy:-$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really have to do is edit a system variable, `$PS1`, to be exact.

You would have to edit the `~/.bashrc` file to make it permanent. Otherwise, it would only stay in effect until the user quit the terminal, then it would revert back.

Read here for a more in depth solution: http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html

Quote:

> It also supports configurable prompts - most people realize this, but
>   don't know how much can be done

...

> The appearance of the prompt is governed by the shell variable PS1.

You can either manually enter it this way, or follow what @Requist answered and use the `sudo hostname reddy` command and do it the easy way (we all like easy, right? :D)

Answer (score 5):

Narashima is the hostname of the machine, you can alter is by issuing the command:

```
sudo hostname reddy
```

If you open a new shell it will read narasimha@reddy:-$

Answer (score -2):

It can be not possible, but there are 2 ways, don't know.

**Case 1 (easier)**

Make a new account "reddy" and look up the terminal. See if it works.

**Case 2**

Well, you might need a reinstall. When you install, in the username type reddy, and when you finally install the OS, make an account named "narasimha".

Case 2 is probably going to work, but I have no idea. Try the Case 1 first.

Comment: Good, but it can be done easier with the $PS1 bash system variable. When the user set up his/her system, they set the hostname to narasimha as well as the username. Your solutions would set the prompt to `reddy@narasimha-$`.

Comment: I'm posting the easiest way, tbh I have no idea what are you talking about :P

I am pretty positive that the asker will have no idea how to do it as well, because she's new to Ubuntu :)

Comment: In any case, the part after the `@` is the hostname, not the username - so creating a new account "reddy" would result in `reddy@narasimha` NOT `narasimha@reddy`

Comment: Just said that :D

Comment: Yeah I'd think it would work that way, but I couldn't test it, as I'm not home. Whatever

Comment: Silly Xylo... it's username@hostname!

Comment: i know, i know, my fault

Comment: What you are suggesting would change the user name (and create a new user, which he may not want), not change the hostname.