# Change the value of root@example with Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

When I connect with the Terminal on Mac, I see:

```
root@example:~#
```

How can I change the value of `example` ?

Is it the hostname ?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually what follows after the @ is the hostname, but it's defined in $PS1 so it could be just a [*hardcoded*] string.  Use `echo $PS1` to see what makes up your PS1 prompt value.  (`info bash` can provide more details)

Comment: @guiverc, it returns me `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`. What it means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change my command line (bash) prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397344/)

Comment: search for PROMPTING section  (or look at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the hostname but the name of the computer/pc which you have assigned and to change it

1) Go to **settings**

2) Then go to **details** (last option)

3) You can see the version of your ubuntu as well as the configuration of your system. There is an option called **Device name** (which must be set to example) change the 'example' with whatever name you want to choose then close the settings tab and open a terminal to check if the name has been changed successfully.